# Proof that Polynomials Form a Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, taylor-expansion

I'm not even sure this is a true statement, but can someone prove that the polynomials form a basis for the set of continuous functions? This seems to be motivation for Taylor series, and several of the eigenbasis in quantum mechanics.

Comment: Presumably you mean a [Schauder basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis) because a [Hamel basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamel_basis#Related_notions) would never leave the polynomials.

Comment: And the *entire* set of polynomials obviously contains linearly dependent sets, so I guess you meant a subset of the polynomials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polynomials form a vector space, and that is certainly not a basis for anything. They are dense in the space of continuous functions on a compact interval with the uniform norm (Weierstraß's theorem), and in many other interesting function spaces as well. The eigenspaces in quantum mechanics is certainly a good example.

This density is not a good motivation for Taylor series, however. They are better motivated by a desire to get really good local approximations around a point; that they often converge to the function they are made from, seems almost coincidental.

When you talk about a basis, you are perhaps thinking of a basis for the polynomials. Any sequence $(p_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ of polynomials, where $p_n$ has exact degree $n$, forms a basis for the polynomials. In quantum mechanics, it is common to get such a basis by using Gram–Schmidt orthogonalization to the natural basis $1,x,x^2,\ldots$, which typically gives you a basis for some Hilbert space of functions.

I could go on (and on), but this topic is too big to handle in this format.

Comment: Why are Taylor Series used for local approximation though? What about natural number exponents works for Taylor Series?

Comment: Well, if you differentiate $x^a$ enough times, where $a$ is not an integer, you will get a singularity. But most functions you see in practice are infinitely differentiable, so non-integral powers aren't all that useful. As for why Taylor series, or rather Taylor polynomials, it's a natural generalization of differentiability. Having $f$ differentiable at $a$ means that $f$ is very well approximated by a first degree polynomial around $a$, after all …

Comment: … and next, you realize that if $f'$ is differentiable at $a$, so it is very well approximated by a first degree polynomial, then you integrate that to get $f$ closely approximated by a second degree polynomial. To repeat that idea, next you get $f'$ approximated by a second degree polynomial. Integrate, get $f$ approximated by a third degree polynomial. And so it goes.

Answer (score 1):

[Relevant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)

You can very-well approximate continuous functions using polynomials.

However, this polynomial is not necessarily a truncated Taylor Series.

Answer (score 1):

They are not.  By definition, a subset $B$ of a vector space $V$ allows you to express every vector $f\in V$ as a linear combination of vectors in $B$ -- that is a weighted *finite* sum of vectors in $B$.  So $f=\exp$ cant't obviously not be exressed as a *finite* sum of polynomials.

Comment: The word "basis" is applied in other contexts too, not just the vector space basis definition. See [Schauder basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis)

Comment: A Schauder basis applies to vector spaces; I know that the noun *basis* occurs in non-vector-spaces-contexts as well.  But similar to Hilbert bases a Schauder basis is not a basis at all.

Comment: Ah sure, I did not express that very clearly. Of course both bases are used in vector spaces. What I mean is that the one you are describing is a Hamel basis, which by definition uses only finite linear combinations, and indeed is the standard notion for basis in linear algebra. Schauder bases use countable linear combinations. For some people who work in such spaces, that's what they think of as "a basis." If that's what the OP is thinking of then it is not ruled out by definition. Regards